# QPainter::drawImage prints different size than QImage::save and print from Photoshop

Tags: qt, printing, scale

I'm scaling a QImage, currently as so (I understand there may be more elegant ways):

```
img.setDotsPerMeterX(img.dotsPerMeterX() * 2);
img.setDotsPerMeterY(img.dotsPerMeterY() * 2);
```

When I save:

```
img.save("c:\\users\\me\\desktop\\test.jpg");
```

and subsequently open and print the image from Photoshop, it is, as expected, half of the physical size of the same image without the scaling applied.

However, when I simply print the scaled QImage, directly from code:

```
myQPainter.drawImage(0,0,img);
```

the image prints at the original physical size - not scaled to half the physical size.

I'm using the same printer in each case; and, as far as I can tell, the settings are consistent between both print cases.

Am I misunderstanding something? The end goal is to successfully scale and print the scaled image directly from code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for [setDotsPerMeterX](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setDotsPerMeterX) it states: -

> Together with dotsPerMeterY(), this number defines the intended scale and aspect ratio of the image, and **determines the scale at which QPainter will draw graphics on the image**. It does not change the scale or aspect ratio of the image when it is rendered on other paint devices.

I expect that the reason for the latter case being the original size is that the image has already been drawn before the call to the functions to set the dots per meter. Or alternatively, set the dots per meter on the original image, before loading its content.

In contrast, when saving, it appears that the device which you save to is copying the values you have set for the dots per meter on the image, then drawing to that device.

I would expect creating a second QImage, setting its dots per meter, then copying from the original to that second image, it would achieve the result you're looking for. Alternatively, you may just be able to set the dots per meter before loading the content on the original QImage.